# Effectivebasepermission: why 32?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

Using REST API call, i am trying to get the list of available subsites for the current user, below is the endpoint uri used

```
/_api/web/Webs$select=Title,URL,effectivebasepermissions&$filter=effectivebasepermissions/high%20gt%2032
```

Why is a `filter gt 32` used?

Answer (score 2):

SPBasePermissions is implemented as a bitmask, which allows a number of values to be stored in a single integer. This concept is commonly used in security scenarios. The number 32 represents the minimum permission needed to view the site.

A general intro to bitmasks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

James Tsai's explanations of bitmasks as they pertain the SPBasePermissions. A little old but still relevant:

http://www.jamestsai.net/Blog/post/Understand-SharePoint-Permissions-Part-1-SPBasePermissions-in-Hex2c-Decimal-and-Binary-The-Basics.aspx

http://www.jamestsai.net/Blog/post/Understand-SharePoint-Permissions-Part-2-Check-SharePoint-usergroup-permissions-with-Permissions-web-service-and-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: I have already read James Tsai's blog regarding SPBasePermissions but is it really supposed to be high value greater than 32? 

I found a mistake regarding the usage of 32. I have tried a permission in a subsite with high value greater than 32 (say for example 48: a combination of UseRemoteAPIs and UseClientIntegration), it will show the subsite but when i click on it System.UnauthorizedAccess exception is thrown. Are there any better way for listing only the available subsite for a certain user?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there is an existing SharePoint method that gets subsites that are only accessible by current user - [GetSubwebsFilteredForCurrentUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh630700(v=office.12).aspx). It is more appropriate rather than using "$filter=effectivebasepermissions/high%20gt%2032".